# Passing data from Contact to Opportunity

Tags: lightning, opportunity

When a user in SFDC goes to a contact and creates a new opportunity we want to carry over some of the data from the Contact into that opp.

We typically do this with a custom button to pass URL parameters however we're migrating to lightning and that's obviously not an option.

How are other folks going about passing data from contact to opp?

Comment: Lightning quick actions? There is plenty of documentation and trailhead modules on the subject.

Comment: Quick Actions can only create a record for whom the Object select is Parent, found worth mentioning. You would have to create a custom lightning component, that fetches value from Contact and create Opp. But can be done.

Comment: It depends. If you need a UI interaction, you will need to build a custom component and you can use [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) for that purpose to populate default values. If you don't need a UI interaction, you can use trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration/units/javascript_buttons_to_lightning_actions).

> Lightning component actions are custom actions that invoke a Lightning component. They support Apex and JavaScript and provide a secure way to build client-side custom functionality.

This would be the best approach for passing data from an existing/newly created record to another one. As to how and what exactly you want your action to do is really up to you.